# group_concat_max_len set in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using [mysql npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package in node application , I have a query where I am using group_concat

```
select 
 group_concat(tpr.parentId) as tmParentIds
 from user AS U LEFT JOIN tm_parent_relationship tpr ON U.userId = tpr.tmId
 where U.userRole = '5' AND U.userStatus = 1 AND U.userId = 223
 group by U.userId
 ORDER BY U.userId DESC
```

which should return long character (more than 1024) but is is only sending 1024 character long string , which is its default feature . 
How to increase length , I could not find anywhere in node perspective .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: something like `connection.query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = value')` ...

Answer (score 4):

```
connection.query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000');



connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
    return cb(error,results);
});
```